# How to use Edge Chromium webdriver "unknown error: cannot find MSEdge binary"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge, chromium

I am trying to use the WebDriver for the Edge Chromium version with PostMan, but I cannot make it work.

WebDriver Download: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver

I try to add the Edge Chromium and Webdriver in the system PATH environment variable and no difference. I think the selenium implementation in java work with the Edge Chromium Webdriver

```
msedgedriver.exe --port 9515
```

POST localhost:9515/session

```
{
   "capabilities":{
      "firstMatch":[
         {

         }
      ],
      "alwaysMatch":{
         "browserName":"MicrosoftEdge",
         "platformName":"windows",
         "goog:chromeOptions":{
            "extensions":[

            ],
            "args":[

            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "desiredCapabilities":{
      "browserName":"MicrosoftEdge",
      "version":"",
      "platform":"WINDOWS",
      "goog:chromeOptions":{
         "extensions":[

         ],
         "args":[

         ]
      }
   }
}
```

```
{
    "value": {
        "error": "unknown error",
        "message": "unknown error: cannot find MSEdge binary",
        "stacktrace": 
"Backtrace:\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00007FF6678D7C52+1932370]\n\tOrdinal0 
[0x00007FF66783CDA2+1297826]\n\tOrdinal0 
[0x00007FF6677A0A51+658001]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00007FF667710F1F+69407]\n\tOrdinal0 
[0x00007FF66770EF02+61186]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00007FF667737DBD+228797]\n\tOrdinal0 
[0x00007FF6677351AF+217519]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00007FF66771706F+94319]\n\tOrdinal0 
[0x00007FF66771822E+98862]\n\tOrdinal0 
[0x00007FF66785B531+1422641]\n\tGetHandleVerifier 
[0x00007FF6679991E9+656297]\n\tGetHandleVerifier 
[0x00007FF667998F81+655681]\n\tGetHandleVerifier 
[0x00007FF6679A104C+688652]\n\tGetHandleVerifier 
[0x00007FF6679999C3+658307]\n\tOrdinal0 
[0x00007FF66785177E+1382270]\n\tOrdinal0 
[0x00007FF66785D9D6+1432022]\n\tOrdinal0 
[0x00007FF66785C84D+1427533]\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk 
[0x00007FF909056FD4+20]\n\tRtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF90AB5B1F1+33]\n"
    }
}
```

The WebDriver should open and be able to execute other commands

Comment: I tried to test the issue with postman and edgedriver (chromium). I am getting the similar error as yours. https://i.postimg.cc/XvPmJ2zy/315.png I also try to test it with Chromedriver but I got same error. It can be possible that we are missing any step or passing the incorrect argument. I will try to search further and let you know about my searching results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to refer steps below may help to solve the issue.

(1) First try to set the environment variable for your Edge (chromium) application.

(2) Try to open PowerShell window and try to launch the Edge web driver.

(3) Launch the Postman app and try to use **http://localhost:9515/session** as **POST** request.

(4) Add code below as body of the request.

```
{
    "desiredCapabilities": {
            "nativeEvents": false,
            "browserName": "edg",
            "version": "",
            "platform": "ANY",
            "javascriptEnabled": true,
            "takesScreenshot": true,
            "handlesAlerts": true,
            "databaseEnabled": true,
            "locationContextEnabled": true,
            "applicationCacheEnabled": false,
            "browserConnectionEnabled": true,
            "cssSelectorsEnabled": true,
            "webStorageEnabled": true,
            "rotatable": true
    }
}
```

(5) Try to send the request.

Reference:

[SeleniumHQ/selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#session-1)

Notes:

- Your environment variable should properly set and referenced to your
  Edge (chromium) correctly.
- Use the supported version of Edge web driver with your Edge
  (chromium) browser.

Comment: Thank work perfectly with only
```json
{
    "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "edg",
            "version": "",
            "platform": "ANY"
    }
}
```
results:
```json
{
    "value": {
        "build": {
            "version": "80.0.320.0 (c7c5bf4fbf6f8237906b4176f220d77983cd5054)"
        },
        "message": "MSEdgeDriver ready for new sessions.",
        "os": {
            "arch": "x86_64",
            "name": "Windows NT",
            "version": "10.0.18980"
        },
        "ready": true
    }
}
```

Comment: From your last comment, it looks like your issue is solved. I suggest you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thank for the advice

Comment: FatherlyNick:

This should really be a comment and not a full answer (ridiculous reputation system tbh); Anyway, to add to Deepak-MSFT's answer - after adding the environment variables be sure to restart your IDE.

I added my MSEdge directory to the PATH and Eclipse would still complain. Everything worked after I closed and re-opened Eclipse.

Also check if you are pointing to MSEdge.exe or the directory where MSEdge.exe is located. I noticed that it only works if you point to the dir and not the .exe. So it would be something like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\

Answer (score 2):

This should really be a comment and not a full answer (ridiculous reputation system tbh); Anyway, to add to Deepak-MSFT's answer - after adding the environment variables be sure to restart your IDE.

I added my `MSEdge` directory to the `PATH` and Eclipse would still complain. Everything worked after I closed and re-opened Eclipse.

Also check if you are pointing to `MSEdge.exe` or the directory where `MSEdge.exe` is located. I noticed that it only works if you point to the dir and not the `.exe`.
So it would be something like: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\`

Comment: I put it in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I did face the same issue, and trust me I tried doing every possible thing, but you know what helped me, though it might sound lame to you, the Edge browser version it was old, when I updated it, it worked for me, the error was resolved, do give it a shot as well

Unlike Chrome browser it does not throws error lie the browser driver version and browser are incompatible.

Yours's sincerely,
A frustrated Automation tester